# Mozilla Add-on development: Chrome page action equivalent?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've Googled around a bit looking for an answer but everything I've found so far is out-dated. Is there anything similar to the Google Chrome Page Action for a Mozilla Firefox Addon?

Or is there a good way to disable/gray-out the browser action icon in Firefox to let users know they can't use the extension unless an appropriate URL is accessed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent of browser action buttons are those within the `sdk/ui/button` namespace:

- [`sdk/ui/button/action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action)
- [`sdk/ui/button/toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle)

These are a relatively recent addition to Firefox (29). If you need such buttons in earlier versions of Firefox, take a look at my [`browseraction-jplib` module](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib).

Comment: Great, thank you! I'll just make the requirement for the addon to be Firefox 29+.